# pow() always returns 0 if I have a negative exponent

Tags: c, math, double, exponential, pow

```
double calculate(int time){
    double timeD = (double)time;
    timeD = timeD*(pow(10,-12));
    return timeD;
}
```

It always returns `0.000000`.

How could I easily manage a negative exponent power?

Comment: gcc appears to disagree: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNDsIgEIX3nILUmIBpjfVvU9uVx3CDQC0JhaaCLkzPjqXY6Mowm8m892XeZGh2o9S5hVBUWsbhqSWmWTcV@Cp3w4T2EmDaXiWHlEhqJTEcCWWgES3HLwDH@vheOcMSojBjPxcTMDtTX6FOP1G@SbMjxsHvubG9CnYBBgB8QEuEQg8tGIYhputHuUZJWVZwWV9Ukv6clM@7/lPbSGwXy@2jwUM8OT1mcO4N "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: It is likely that the problem is in the code not shown. Could you provide a [mre] please.

Comment: sorry, I edited the post. Not -6, but -12 instead. This is for the machine precision. Is there a way to display the result in a better precision than double?

Comment: If the question is to fix your code, you need to update it with the caller-side code printing etc. If the question is if `long double` exists, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 4):

To print very small/large values, prefer `"%g"`

```
printf("%f\n", 1E-12); // 0.000000
printf("%g\n", 1E-12); // 1e-12
```

or use the precision specifier for floating-point conversion

```
printf("%.12f\n", 1E-12); // 0.000000000001
//       ^^^ 12 digits of precision
```

Answer (score 0):

add **#include <math.h>** in Header

your code could be like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double calculate(int time){
    double timeD = (double)time;
    timeD = timeD*(pow(10,-6));
    return timeD;
}


int main()
{   
    float x;
    x = calculate(5);
    printf("%f", x);
    return 0;
}
```